# Created date (created_at) and Updated date (updated_at) are different in php and mysql

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have custom table and attachment is a structure of the database.
[image]
I Save data with

```
$post_data['created_date'] = now();
$model = Mage::getModel("rapnet/rapnet")->addData($post_data)->save();
```

Created date is now() and updated date is "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". So why both are different on my localhost? How can we solve this to keep both same while creating a new record?

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue early (it because your database set to one locale, but server to another).

So, here is a solution.

**First**: don't use `now()` function, use `Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp();` in Magento.

**Second**: don't use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value for your magento database. Set both `created_at` and `updated_at` fields to `DATETIME` type.

Just use this upgrade script:

```
$installer = $this;
$table = $installer->getTable('model/entity'); // values from your config.xml here
$installer->startSetup();
$table->addColumn($table, 'created_at', [
    'type'     => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
    'comment'  => 'created_at',
]);
$table->addColumn($table, 'updated_at', [
    'type'     => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
    'comment'  => 'updated_at'
]);
$installer->endSetup();
```

or this (if you already have these columns):

```
$installer = $this;
$table = $installer->getTable('model/entity'); // values from your config.xml here
$installer->startSetup();
$table->modifyColumn($table, 'created_at',[
    'type'     => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
    'comment'  => 'created_at',
]);
$table->modifyColumn($table, 'updated_at',[
    'type'     => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
    'comment'  => 'updated_at'
]);
$installer->endSetup();
```

**Third**: in your model add function `_beforeSave()`(and you shouldn't set date manually anymore) and in that function make next logic: if it just created set `created_at` to current time using function above, and set `updated_at` to current time.

It looks like:

```
public function _beforeSave()
{
    if($this->isObjectNew()){
        $this->setCreatedAt(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp());
    }
    $this->setUpdatedAt(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp());
    return parent::_beforeSave();
}
```

**Fourth**: also it is good practice in magento to call your columns `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Hope it will be helpful for you **:)**

Comment: don't you want to use Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate() instead? as Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp() uses the magento timestamp

Answer (score 0):

This is timezone issue, mysql save `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in UTC format while your application `time()` may be picking your server timezone.
You need to keep timezone same for both column. [For more see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060263/4155637)

Comment: Bro. I know this is a timezone issue. The difference is 5 hours. Updated date is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which is inserted with Mysql.And Php function is behind with 5:30Hours. And my IST time is also -5:30. But I am in localhost so how it's possible for this?

Comment: Bro localhost is also server, You need to check  timezone on your localhost eg. echo date_default_timezone_get(); and manage then you can update according to your need